# Kotlin-Java Script Warnings coming for basic project

Tags: javascript, kotlin, warnings

I am trying to execute  a basic Kotlin JS project but getting warnings. pls help how to fix the warnings.

```js
Compiled with problems:X

WARNING

asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  WordCountWeb4.js (254 KiB)


WARNING

entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (254 KiB)
      WordCountWeb4.js


WARNING

webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
```

[Image to Show what I am doing and getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk3WQ.gif)

Answer (score 3):

It's the limit of webpack. You can use KotlinWebpackConfig.Mode.DEVELOPMENT to ignore this issue.

```kotlin
kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport.enabled = true
                mode = org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpackConfig.Mode.DEVELOPMENT
            }
        }
    }
}
```